# My iTunes app description always appear in English

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I set the primary language to Thai with Thai description on the iTunes connect then submit the app.

Now the app status is ready for sale.

I changed my iPhone language to Thai then search my app on the Appstore. My application shows description in English.

Why does the description not show in Thai?

Answer (score 0):

Phone language does not affect on the appstore application descriptions. You should change your appstore country or region to see it. Or you can set your application's *Primary Language* as Thai while you are adjusting your app details in itunes connect.

You can find additional information about changing appstore location in [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389) link.

You can also find information about setting app languages in [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html) link.